# Storybook: Radio with no options (or select)

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have this basic story:

```js
const meta = {
    title: 'Text',
    component: Text,
    args: {
        children: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
        Libero inventore ad dicta obcaecati quisquam dignissimos est quas, autem explicabo 
        facilis laboriosam expedita, aliquid sequi dolores voluptatum illum maiores, 
        repudiandae cupiditate.',
        theme: 'dark',
        size: 'medium',
        uppercase: false,
    },
    argTypes: {
        children: { type: 'string' },
        theme: {
            control: {
                type: 'inline-radio',
                options: ['dark', 'light']
            }
        },
        size: {
            control: {
                type: 'inline-radio',
                options: ['small', 'medium', 'large', 'huge']
            }
        },
        uppercase: { type: 'boolean' }
    },
    
};

export default meta;

const Template = (args) => {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={args.theme === 'dark' ? theme.dark : theme.light}>
            <GlobalStyles />
            <Text {...args}></Text>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};

export const Text_Dark = {
    render: Template,
}
```

Lets take for example, the "size" argType: "size" is a valid and present component attribute, here is how the Text component should be like, (WITH THE SIZE ATTRIBUTE):

```js
export function Text({children, size, uppercase}) { // Here, the size attribute is present

    return (
        <>
            <Styled.Text size={size} $uppercase={uppercase}>{children}</Styled.Text>
        </>
    );
}
```

However, theme attribute is not an attribute that i want to keep in my component... It's only an attribute for Storybook deal with it.

Based on that, i want to display a control with radio or select buttons for my "theme" argType. However, when i do that:

```js
theme: {
            control: {
                type: 'inline-radio',
                options: ['dark', 'light']
            }
        },
```

The result is basic a "-" and a warning in the console "Radio with no options".

How to fix that, maintaining the concept of my "theme" argType not being present in my component attributes, that is, not like size, but a storybook only attribute ?